# reading pg_dump file occurs at open the file

Tags: python, dump

I'm using the [pgdumplib](https://pypi.org/project/pgdumplib/) lib. Unfortunately there is an error, when I'm trying to open the file. The file is in the same folder as the python script. I'm using Python 3.7

**Code:**

```
import pgdumplib

dump = pgdumplib.load('test.dump')

print('Database: {}'.format(dump.toc.dbname))
print('Archive Timestamp: {}'.format(dump.toc.timestamp))
print('Server Version: {}'.format(dump.toc.server_version))
print('Dump Version: {}'.format(dump.toc.dump_version))

for line in dump.table_data('public', 'pgbench_accounts'):
    print(line)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/data/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    dump = pgdumplib.load('test.dump')
  File "C:\Users\user\venv\data\lib\site-packages\pgdumplib\__init__.py", line 24, in load
    return dump.Dump(converter=converter).load(filepath)
  File "C:\Users\user\venv\data\lib\site-packages\pgdumplib\dump.py", line 228, in load
    raise ValueError('Path {!r} does not exist'.format(path))
ValueError: Path 'test.dump' does not exist
```

Comment: Try with the full path to the file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running your code from `C:/Users/user/700Joach/project/` and you have the following line in your script:

```
dump = pgdumplib.load('test.dump')
```

Then, python would look for the following path to open `test.dump`:

```
C:/Users/user/700Joach/project/test.dump
```

Namely, this part: `load('test.dump')` internally is forging a relative path to `test.dump`.

You can do several things to resolve the issue. Either move `test.dump` to the directory from which you are executing your code. Or, provide an absolute path to your `test.dump` as follows:

```
dump = pgdumplib.load('C:/Users/user/700Joach/project/test.dump')
```